# Controlar progressBar desde un hilo que ejecuta un metodo en otra clase

Tags: c#, hilos, progressbar

disculpen tengo un problema que resolver y es que tengo un progressbar en mi form1 y en este form  tengo un botón para que comience un hilo para subir una lista a una BD  en lotes de 150 registros cada 60s, mi pregunta es, como podría hacer mi progressbar avance desde la otra clase ?aquí el fragmento del código

Este es el codigo del boton.

```
  private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (comboTablas.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            List<ProductosWeb> listaProductos = ConsultasTablasSql.GetListaProductos();
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => CargarTablas.InsertarTablaProductos(listaProductos));
            thread.Start();
        }
```

y este es el codigo de mi metodo en la otra clase.

```
public class CargarTablas
{
    public static void InsertarTablaProductos(List<ProductosWeb> listaProductos)
    {
       DBServices services = new DBServices();
        for (int x = 0; x < listaProductos.Count; x++)
        {
            services.InsertProductoWeb(listaProductos[x]);//Insertamos Registros
            if (x % 150 == 0 && x >= 1 && x < listaProductos.Count) { Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000); }//Revisamos que cada x registros va a esperar n segundos para seguir insertando 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Eventos? un proceso async? probaste algo de eso?